Gauge condition for EM field with or without 4-current
In deriving the plane-wave mode expansion for classical $A^\mu$ field, we start with free field Lagrangian without interaction with $j^\mu_{\text{em}}$
$$
\require{cancel}\mathcal{L}_A = -\frac14 F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} - \xcancel{j^{\mu}_{\text{em}} A_\mu},
$$
which gives EoM of
$$
\require{cancel}\square A^\nu - \partial^\nu (\partial^\mu A_\mu) = 0 + \xcancel{j^\nu_{\text{em}}}.
$$
Then firstly we take $A^\mu \to A'^\mu = A^\mu - \partial^\mu\chi$ to satisfy Lorenz gauge $\partial_\mu A'^\mu = 0$ and thus have EoM
$$
\require{cancel}\square A'^\mu = 0 + \xcancel{j^\mu_{\text{em}}}
$$
with plane-wave solution and Lorenz condition
$$
A'^\mu = N \epsilon^\mu e^{-ik\cdot x},\quad \epsilon^\mu k_\mu = 0.
$$
Next, by taking $A'^\mu \to A''^\mu = A'^\mu - \partial^\mu \tilde{\chi}$ with $\tilde{\chi}$ satisfying $\square\tilde{\chi} = 0$, we could have solution with Lorenz condition and EoM
$$
\require{cancel}A''^\mu = N(\epsilon^\mu + \beta k^\mu) e^{-ik \cdot x} = N \epsilon'^\mu e^{-ik\cdot x},\quad \epsilon'^\mu k_\mu = 0,\quad \square A''^\mu = 0 + \xcancel{j^\mu_{\text{em}}}
$$
since $k^\mu$ is null vector. Here we obtain another arbitarty parameter $\beta$ to be chosen, and it's convenient to have $\beta=-\epsilon^0/k^0$ such that $\epsilon'^0 = 0$ and thus $\mathbf{\epsilon}'\cdot\mathbf{k} = 0$.
And here comes my question. In the last equation above it seems that $\epsilon'^0 = 0$ leads to $A''^0 = 0$, and therefore Lorenz condition $\partial_\mu A''^\mu$ yeilds $\nabla \cdot\mathbf{A}''=0$, which seems to be Coulomb gauge. I know we can take both of these gauge conditions to be satisfied only if $j^\mu_{\text{em}} = 0$, but I'm wondering whether this can be shown in a way that if we take the second gauge choice $A'^\mu\to A''^\mu$ when $j^\mu_{\text{em}}$ doesn't vanish in Lagrangian, then there must be some contradicitions.
